# How to get Formula Description for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, formula, formula-field

The "MailTempRenewalHosyuStart__c" in Contract object is formula of text.

I wrote as below.

"★Detail★

```
"&BR()
&BR()
&( Field4__r.Name) &BR()
&TEXT( C__Contact__r.Field1__c )&" "&( C__Contact__r.LastName)&" "&","&BR()
```

In Field Display

★Detail★

```
ABC Company
Mr. Michel ,
```

I'd like to show "MailTempRenewalHosyuStart__c" in lightning component of LWC. I want to have line breaks same as Field display. but LWC shows 
 and no line break.
but below show.

★Detail★

```
<br><br>ABC Company<br>Mr. Michel ,<br>
```

The codes are below.

●mtempNew1.html

```
<template>
    <template if:true={contract.data}>
      <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:800px;">
        <p>
          <lightning-formatted-text value={description}></lightning-formatted-text>
        </p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
```

●mtempNew1.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
export default class mtempNew1 extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, {
      recordId: "$recordId",
      fields: ["Contract.MailTempRenewalHosyuStart__c"]
    })
    contract;
  
    get description() {
      return this.contract.data.fields.MailTempRenewalHosyuStart__c.value;
    }
  }
```

●mtempNew1.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: This will happen to avoid scripting attacks (so is a security feature). It is best to perform formatting in the UI, so have the LWC do all the necessary work instead of a formula.

Comment: Yes, That’s right. I will create a original new one for lectures.

Answer (score 0):

You can display HTML content using lightning-formatted-rich-text instead of lightning-formatted-text.

In the LWC html file you provide replace lightning-formatted-text component with the component to make the description field work.